# I accidentally overwritted some angular2 files with ng init. Is there any way to get it back?

Tags: linux, angular, backup, angular-cli

I accidentally overwritted some angular2-cli files with ng init.

app.module.ts and angular-cli.json

Is there any way to get it back? I have no GIT installed.

Comment: Sorry for  your pain, but this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: If you are in a corporate environment, see if your system backups have anything helpful for you. If you are on your own, then if you don't have a backup system in place, the only thing to consider is a data recovery service (which will be very expensive, time consuming and may or may not work). Data recovery means you need to stop writing any/all data to that hard drive NOW. Good luck.